# Asp.Net&JavaScript: Problem With Image Slide

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to slide background on hover.
I used the code below in HTML webpage once and it worked correctly.
But when I tried to use it in my ASPX page, first it gave this error:
"Microsoft JScript RunTime Error: '$' is undeclared"
So I deleted the 1st $ before function(). But I couldn't make it work still.
Any ideas why it does not work?
Code is:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#vertical div a").hover(function () {
                $("img", this).stop().animate({ top: "-173px" }, { queue: false, duration: 400 });
            }, function () {
                $("img", this).stop().animate({ top: "0px" }, { queue: false, duration: 400 });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .altikisilik
        {
            display: block;
            background: url('Images/Default/Brazil_bg.png') top;
        }

        #vertical div
        {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #vertical img
        {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="vertical" class="clear" runat="server">
        <div>
            <a class="altikisilik" href="Default.aspx">
                <img src="Images/Default/Brazil.png" border="0" alt="Brazil" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the jQuery script include anywhere in your code. I think that would be the issue

Comment: I know it was a real dumb point to miss but I wasn't expecting myself to be that dumb. Sorry and thanks for the answer. Now there'a action.

Comment: its an easy mistake to make ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must include jquery library above the rest of your javascript.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I added locally but thanks for the remote link, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

you should download the jquery.js from the site:www.jquery.com .Or use the google api support .In fact you should import the jquery file. choose one of the below:

this method you should put the jquery-1.6.2.min.js download from the site www.jquery.com to the folder where you put your sites,

or simply use the google support :

Comment: Thanks, I was stupid to miss to add Jquery. It's allright now.